# How can I plot a bar with totals without the header in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, stacked-bar-chart

I want to plot a bar with total labels based on my df. But, the totals appear off by one row. The plot includes the header row, so the totals are misplaced. Here is the header and first 3 rows of my df and my code:

```
    Ethnicity    Bachelor   Master   Doctorate
1   Chinese      278270     101555   21015
2   Black        82855      38475    6350
3   Filipino     182845     8845     885
```

```
ax = df.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, figsize=(15,6), width=.5)
totals = df.sum(axis=1)
y_offset = 4
for i, total in enumerate(totals):
  ax.text(totals.index[i], total + y_offset, round(total), ha="center")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your dataframe's index is starting from 1. So, you need to offset by 1 the x-coordinate of the texts:

```py
ax.text(totals.index[i]-1, total + y_offset, round(total), ha="center")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I previously tried a lot to set the header out of the plot and make it work, but what you did is very quick and simple. :)

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. :) Please, mark this answer as the solution to this question.